# how to turn json file into Javascript string var

Tags: javascript, json, requirejs

I want to load a json local (I mean it's in the same folder as my index.htm) as a string var in Javascript.

I tried something like that:

```
var json = require('state.json');
```

But it doesn't work. So i tried the other version like this:

```
var json = require(['state.json']);
```

And it failed again.

If I can avoid using XMLHttpRequest it would be fine.

Comment: You'll have to use XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: are you using requirejs?

Comment: @DanielA.White Yes I am.

Answer (score 0):

Security settings in browsers will not let you interact with the file system through JavaScript. You have to serve it from a web server.

Comment: ok, then something like:
`
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open("get", "get.php?url=" + url);
http.onreadystatechange = myfonction;
`
would work?

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using RequireJS, I would suggest using the JSON plugin.

```
var json = require('json!state.json');
```

or if you really want it as a string, use the TEXT plugin.

```
var text = require('text!state.json');
```

Comment: With this I will get a json object and not a string right?

Comment: the json plugin will parse it where as the text plugin won't